# Did Michael Shannon appear in Batman v Superman, or was it just CGI?

Tags: casting, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

In "Batman vs Superman", the character Zod appears briefly as a corpse. Actor Michael Shannon - who portrayed Zod in "Man of Steel" - is credited as Zod, but in the actual cameo his face looks a little... off. I'm not sure if it's because his face is CGI'd in, or if it's makeup to make him look dead. Either way, Shannon would get a credit in the film credits. Granted, it's a testament to the state of CGI technology that I can't tell the difference.

**Did Michael Shannon actually film the Zod scene in BvS or was it post-production work?**

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**Michael Shannon Never Stepped Foot On Batman V Superman Set**

In a recent interview with *Metro UK*, *Shannon* talked about his work on BvS.

> “To be honest, I never went to the set of that movie ever,” he said. “I did some ADR, I recorded some lines that Zack [Snyder, director] wasn’t even sure he was going to use — like, creepy s— I’d be saying to Lex Luthor in the spirit world or wherever. I don’t even know if it’s in the movie or not. I do seem to recall a giant, rubber, naked version of my body.”
>   <sub>[Link](http://comicbook.com/dc/2016/11/17/michael-shannon-never-stepped-foot-on-batman-v-superman-set/)</sub>

and,

> Of course, fans already knew that *Shannon* was only seen in the film as a corpse, and that body was made from *wax*.
>  *Jesse Eisenberg*, who played *Lex Luthor*, told *Conan O’Brien* that the dummy was anatomically correct down to the last hair. 
> *Studio ADI* created the body double which used a headcast of *Shannon* and a body mold of *Greg Plitt*.

For more Refer [here](http://comicbook.com/dc/2016/11/17/michael-shannon-never-stepped-foot-on-batman-v-superman-set/).

YouTube video showing how they made it. [ Credits to **[Omegacron](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/15909/omegacron)** ]