# Hugh Jackman's World Record for longest live-action superhero duration

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe

Hugh Jackman shares a [world record](http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/news/2019/2/hugh-jackman-surprised-with-record-title-to-mark-16-year-wolverine-career-561491) with Patrick Stewart for **longest career as a live action Marvel superhero**

From the article linked:

> Jackman holds the record with fellow X-Men star and Star Trek legend Sir Patrick Stewart (UK); both have had careers spanning 16 years 228 days as Wolverine and Professor Charles Xavier (Professor X) respectively.
>
> Both actors made their first appearance as Marvel superheroes in X-Men (2000), with their most recent appearance was in Logan (2017).

However, Hugh Jackman makes an appearance in *Deadpool 2*'s post-credit scene.  Although the role is not credited, other than the actor being thanked by the producers, Deadpool does interact with Hugh Jackman in costume.

Question: Would that appearance not extend Jackman's record one year further than Patrick Stewart?

Comment: It's reused footage, so not sure it counts.

Comment: I'm not going to answer my own question with an update that will soon become obsolete, but Sir Patrick Stewart beat Hugh Jackman's record with an appearance in *Doctor Strange 2: Multiverse of Madness* but Hugh Jackman will retake the title with *Deadpool 3* if the damn thing ever gets released...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You answered your question already:

That appearance does not count since it's reused footage and Hugh doesn't appear in the credits and cast.

As you can see in [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5463162/fullcredits?ref_=tt_ql_1) movie page, Hugh only appears in the thanks section.

Comment: @aryxus said it was reused footage, though I would say it is *edited* footage where two characters (one old and one new) interact.  This interaction is my main reason for considering it an appearance by Wolverine as a character

Comment: @m1gp0z Deadpool footage is edited in the scene, but Wolverine footage remains the same as before.

Comment: Unrelated but *Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice* did credit an actor whose likeness was used in a film in . a different [capacity](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/81450/did-michael-shannon-appear-in-batman-v-superman-or-was-it-just-cgi)

Comment: @m1gp0z Well, but as you can see in the accepted answer, the actor did some work for the movie "I did some ADR, I recorded some lines that Zack [Snyder, director] wasn’t even sure he was going to use". But I think Hugh didn't even want credit to be honest, he's a nice guy.

Comment: I will accept your answer, though I believe Hugh Jackman was asked and gave permission for the use of his likeness.  Even if not credited officially.

Comment: @m1gp0z Yes, I agree, that's why he is in the thanks section, maybe he didn't want credit because he didn't "directly worked in the movie", but the directors thanked him anyway.